# How to use lag function to calculate next observation in SAS

Tags: sas, lag

Suppose the dataset has 3 columns

```
Obs  Theo  Cal  
1    20    20   
2    21    23   
3    21    .    
4    22    .    
5    21    .    
6    23    .
```

`Theo` is the theoretical value while `Cal` is the estimated value.

I need to calculate the missing `Cal`.
For each `Obs`, its `Cal` is a linear combination of previous two `Cal` values.

`Cal(3) = Cal(2) * &coef1 + Cal(1) * &coef2`.
`Cal(4) = Cal(3) * &coef1 + Cal(2) * &coef2`.

But `Cal = lag1(Cal) * &coef1 + lag2(Cal) * &coef2` didn't work as I expected.

Comment: I ran a similar simulation and it worked for me. Can you be more precise ? How and where did you define `coef1` and `coef2` ? What result do you get ? Providing a reproducible example would also help solving your issue.

Comment: @Vincent coef's are two global macro variables. eg. `%let coef1 = 0.38`.  lag1() and lag2() return missing values.

Comment: Code should work fine. Are your lag calculations in an IF or other conditional block? If so, that'll be the issue. You can google conditional lag SAS for explanations of why that doesn't work.

Comment: Turns out I didn't understant well your issue in my first test. My answer should fix it though.

Comment: Don't use lag, use retain.

Comment: @randombet I'm quite certain you aren't giving us the entire code, as the code you give above wouldn't do completely what you ask.  Please include more of your code in the future - the entire sample data step - as it would make it more obvious to answerers where your problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with using lag is when you use lag1(Cal) you're not getting the last value of Cal that was written to the output dataset, you're getting the last value that was passed to the lag1 function.
It would probably be easier to use a retain as follows:

```
data want(drop=Cal_l:);
    set have;
    retain Cal_l1 Cal_l2;

    if missing(Cal) then Cal = Cal_l1 * &coef1 + Cal_l2 * &coef2;

    Cal_l2 = Cal_l1;
    Cal_l1 = Cal;
run;
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand why you combine retain and lag here :)  Nothing inherently wrong with it, just confusing to me.

Comment: Yea, you're right...I just felt like adding it because the question was about lag.  It's actually less efficient to have it.  I had it as Cal_l2 = Cal_l1 before.  I'll change it back.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess you wrote a datastep like so.

```
data want;
  set have;
  if missing(cal) then 
    cal = lag1(cal)*&coef1 + lag2(cal)*&coef2;
run;
```

LAG isn't grabbing a previous value, but is rather creating a queue that is N long and gives you the end piece of.  If you have it behind an IF statement, then you will never put the useful values of CAL into that queue - you'll only be tossing missings into it.  See it like so:

```
data have;
  do x=1 to 10;
    output;
  end;
run;

data want;
  set have;
  real_lagx = lag(x);
  if mod(x,2)=0 then do;
    not_lagx = lag(x);
    put real_lagx= not_lagx=;
  end;
run;
```

The Real lags are the immediate last value, while the NOT lags are the last *even* value, because they're inside the IF.

You have two major options here.  Use RETAIN to keep track of the last two observations, or use LAG like I did above before the IF statement and then use the lagged values inside the IF statement.  There's nothing inherently better or worse with either method; LAG works for what it does as long as you understand it well.  RETAIN is often considered 'safer' because it's harder to screw up; it's also easier to watch what you're doing.

```
data want;
  set have;
  retain cal1 cal2;
  if missing(cal) then cal=cal1*&coef1+cal2*&coef2;
  output;
  cal2=cal1;
  cal1=cal;
run;
```

or

```
data want;
  set have;
  cal1=lag1(cal);
  cal2=lag2(cal);
  if missing(cal) then cal=cal1*&coef1+cal2*&coef2;
run;
```

The latter method will only work if `cal` is infrequently missing - specifically, if it's never missing more than once from any three observations.  In the initial example, the first `cal` (row 3) will be populated, but from there on out it will always be missing.  This may or may not be desired; if it's not, use `retain`.

Comment: I don't think the last example will work because with the lag functions you're only picking up the values of cal from the "have" dataset, which are missing and not the cal you created in the "if missing..." statement.  So you'll just get missing values in the "want" dataset.

Comment: Aaaand we remember why I don't usually use lag.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a way to accomplish it in a `DATA` step but as for me, when I want SAS to process iteratively, I use `PROC IML` and a `do` loop. I named your table `SO` and succesfully ran the following :

```
PROC IML;

    use SO;          /* create a matrix from your table to be used in proc iml */
    read all var _all_ into table;
    close SO;

    Cal=table[,3];

    do i=3 to nrow(cal);               /* process iteratively the calculations */

        if cal[i]=. then do;cal[i]=&coef1.*cal[i-1]+&coef2.*cal[i-2];
        end;else do;end;
    end;

    table[,3]=cal;
    Varnames={"Obs" "Theo" "Cal"};

    create SO_ok from table [colname=varnames];     /* outputs a new table */
    append from table;
    close SO_ok;
QUIT;
```

I'm not saying you couldn't use `lag()` and a `DATA` step to achieve what you want to do. But I find that `PROC IML` is useful and more intuitive when it comes to iterative process.

Comment: The first sentence isn't correct.  LAG (as with everything else in SAS data step) certainly processes row by row.